# Reload authorizers.xml file at runtime

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I want to reload initial admin identity configuration at runtime. Is there any option to achieve this.

Consider the case,
If i have configured NiFi in secure mode using Kerberos and doesn't provided "Initial Admin". So i cannot login into NiFi with any user. I want to update the admin configuration in authorizers.xml after NiFi started and reload the file in runtime.
How can i achieve this?

Give me a solution or idea to make it succeeded.

Comment: but why not to provide initial admin configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot reload the Initial Admin Identity without restarting the application. When you initially configure NiFi, provide the principal as the IAI in `authorizers.xml` and then start the application. If you have not done this, stop the application, modify `authorizers.xml`, and restart the application.

Once you have an IAI which can log in, you can use the user management and policy management tools in NiFi to add other users without having to restart the application.

Comment: Thanks. I know it cannot be done. I hope that i can do some changes to make this possible. I need some alternate solution to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need to reload the IAI without restarting the application?

Comment: In case, there is no such user exists in AD or user account was locked. I have to change the admin account name.