# Multiple initial admin or initial admin group

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have few question on Apache NiFi

1. In NiFi, Can i set more than one user for `Initial Admin Identity`?
2. Also, i want to set a group with admin privileges. Can i add groups in `Initial Admin Identity` property

I have asked to reload authorizers.xml file at runtime
[Reload authorizers.xml file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325413/reload-authorizers-xml-file-at-runtime)

But it is only startup configuration and cannot be done after started NiFi.

3. Is there any single REST API to add admin privilege for a user instead of calling multiple APIs for individual policies.

Answer (score 3):

Only a single user can be specified as the `Initial Admin Identity`. The identity of the `Initial Admin` will be used to create a user. At this point, that user will be able to manage user/groups and policies. Unfortunately, there is no single endpoint for adding additional `Initial Admins`. NiFi employs resource based authorization, so it's up to the `Initial Admin` to assign users/groups to the policies they see fit. I'd suggest opening the Developer Tools of your browser to see the requests in action.

Thanks!